# MUI Input doesn't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Tried to change my normal input to mui input textfield.
Before everything working but now the value doesn't change

```
const handleChangeInput = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value, err: '', success: '' });
};
```

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <TextField
    id='email-textfield'
    label='E-Mail'
    variant='outlined'
    value={email}
    onChange={handleChangeInput}
    fullWidth
  />
</ThemeProvider>
```

My old working code

```
<label className='block mb-1'>
                          Email
</label>
   <input
      type='email'
      placeholder='Email'
      value={email}
      required
      className={`w-full text-white bg-gray-700 outline-none border-2 border-gray-500 ${focusBorder} p-3 rounded`}
      name='email'
      onChange={handleChangeInput}
  ></input>
```

Comment: Could you provide reproduceable sample?

Comment: I think you have forgotten to add `name` attribute in your `<TextField>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name tag was missing.
Thank you @Abhinad Rajopadhyaya

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <TextField
    id='email-textfield'
    label='E-Mail'
    name='email'
    variant='outlined'
    value={email}
    onChange={handleChangeInput}
    fullWidth
  />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: It is better to say thanks in comments. The answer will be pretty clean.